# "VBAProject" name conflict

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-addins

My issue involves PowerPoint Add-Ins all being named VBAProject.

- Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2010 - PowerPoint 2010 32 bit
- Running Windows 7 Pro SP1 64 bit

I have several add-ins for PowerPoint saved as .PPAM files.  In any PowerPoint file I can (or should be able to) link add-ins to extend that presentation's functionality.  Each .PPAM file is named differently.  In the VBA IDE however, in the list of references, each add-in is called 'VBAProject'.  There are multiple entries of 'VBAProject' each one showing a path to a different .PPAM file.  The problem is that I cannot add a reference to more than one add-in because the same name assigned to each of these; VBAProject.  This results in a name conflict.  Using the add-in manager from PowerPoint design view I can see all the selected add-ins as being 'active'.  The Add-in manager for the VBA IDE shows no Add-ins.

Questions:

- Is the naming of PowerPoint Add-ins as 'VBAProject' expected for every add-in?
- Is there a way of change the name 'VBAProject' to something unique and hence avoid the name conflicts?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

So it seems as if I have found the solution to my problem and would like to share it with the community.  It involved a small change to the registry.  [Be careful when dealing w/ the registry and make a back-up prior to any changes.]

From Regedit.exe -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options.  Change value of DebugAddins from 0x00000000 (0) to 0x00000001 (1).

With this done you will be able to see all the add-ins in the VBA IDE and from there you can change the name 'VBAProject' to something unique.